# ugly font in XP, how can I restore it?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, cleartype

The XP SP3 workstation I used in workplace changed font rendering to ugly one in sudden(maybe after rebooting with chkdsk messages). How can I restore the font rendering setting back to normal?

screenshot of comparing between workstation with affected/ugly font (upper part), and other workstation that has normal font(lower part):

[image]

Comment: Wonder if your workplace actually paid for Custom Support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found the root of issue is that, Microsoft pushed a faulty update(KB3013455) that breaks font smoothing(I don't know if this patch breaks font smoothing in NT6.x[i.e. Vista ~ 8.1] or not, but it does break NT5.1 based Windows). For those having this update installed should be removed in order to restore a working font smoothing look.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3013455

Comment: Thanks Roy! I had the same problem in windows 2003 and windows 2008. Please mark your answer as accepted (it's perfectly normal and in fact encouraged)

Comment: There's a fix now. See full info here: http://superuser.com/questions/876582/terrible-font-rendering-in-some-applications-but-not-others/877213#877213

Answer (score 2):

Apparently not all fonts are broken but only some. It's better to substitute fonts with different ones. Security issues fixed by KB3013455 might be important ; )

I've used [Microsoft's Power Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypePowerToy.mspx) to check which fonts look 'ugly'. And substituted Arial, Times New Roman and Courier New with [Liberation alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts).

I've also tried using fonts from Windows 2008 R2, but it didn't help.  To replace the fonts I've [used this approach](https://superuser.com/questions/116929/replace-windows-xp-default-font-tahoma/628116#628116)

> Copy the new font files somewhere to your system (i.e. `C:\Temp\`)
>
> Then use the command line (Windows-Explorer won't work here since it
>   automatically starts the install routine) to copy the files to
>   c:\Windows\Fonts under a different name:
>
> ```
> copy c:\Temp\tahoma.ttf c:\Windows\Fonts\tahoma_0.ttf
> copy c:\Temp\tahomabd.ttf c:\Windows\Fonts\tahomabd_0.ttf
> ```
>
> After that use the Registry-Editor to redirect the font names to the
>   new files:
>
> Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` and find the entries `Tahoma Regular
>   (TrueType)` and `Tahoma Bold (TrueType)` and change it's values from
>   "tahoma.ttf" to "tahoma_0.ttf" and "tahomabd.ttf" to "tahomabd_0.ttf"
>   respectively.
>
> Now you only need to restart your system and then the new font files are used.

Comment: Better solution but for me the rendering of the liberation alternatives produces a moderate result - not as ugly as the original but not good either: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/242368/fonts.png What's your situation?